# MongoDb Query doesn't return all of the time

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a very simple query that I am running against Mongo using the official C# driver 1.8 that only returns from performing the query about 50% of the time.  I have a unit test and if I run the query it will return about 50% of the time in less than a second where as the other times it will never finish.

Below is the query

```
var q = Database.GetCollection<Stuff>("Stuff").AsQueryable()
    .Where(x => x.Partition == partitionName && x.PersistantId != null && (
        (x.When.DateStart > startingFrom && x.When.DateEnd == null) ||
        (x.When.DateEnd > startingFrom)));
return q.ToList();
```

When I take the query and run it in MongoVue using the query below I can get a response in under 1 second.

```
{ "Partition" : "PartitionID:53", "PersistantId" : { "$ne" : null }, "$or" : [{ "When.DateStart" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2012-04-01T06:00:00Z") }, "When.DateEnd" : null }, { "When.DateEnd" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2012-04-01T06:00:00Z") } }] }
```

It seems like perhaps a bug in the 1.8 driver or MongoDB 2.4.1.  The collection only has about 70,000 items and is on a mongo Server running on Windows with 4 gigs of memory and a couple processors.

Are there any diagnostic logs I can look at or perhaps errors with my query?

Comment: when your query is running (and not finishing) run db.currentOp() at the mongo shell prompt.  This will show you all current processes/queries and you can see if it is in fact running or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mongoDB inbuild profiler , I think it will help you to what's really going wrong in your query sometime http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/